# Python 3: Print On Same Line

Tags: python, printing

I'm trying to make text print on the same line for my Hangman game concept. It worked earlier, although after fixing the game up from the majority of errors, I can't seem to get it to work. The code used to print is:

```
def printWord():
    guessedWords = []
    guessedWordsCorrect = []
    selectedWord = 'dog'
    printWordLength = 0
    printWordIndex = 0
    printWord = ''

    while printWordLength < len(selectedWord):
        if selectedWord[printWordIndex] == " ":
                print(" ",end='')
                printWordLength = printWordLength + 1
                printWordIndex = printWordIndex + 1
        else:
            if selectedWord[printWordIndex] in guessedWords:
                print(selectedWord[printWordIndex],"",end='')
                printWordLength = printWordLength + 1
                printWordIndex = printWordIndex + 1
            else:
                print("_ ",end='')
                printWordLength = printWordLength + 1
                printWordIndex = printWordIndex + 1
        print("")
```

I used `end=""` to try to print on the same line, which worked great previously, but no luck this time?

When running the code, all works fine apart from having them print on the same line.

Comment: Why did you delete your question? Deleted questions have no hope of helping anyone else; Stack Overflow answers are not just for your benefit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a newline every loop iteration right after you printed something without a newline:

```
while printWordLength < len(selectedWord):
    # ...
    print("")
```

Move that print statement *out* of the loop:

```
while printWordLength < len(selectedWord):
    # ...

print("")
```